# Как передать данные в мою БД (SQLte) по нажатию кнопки диалога setPositiveButton из DialogFragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragment, dialogfragment

Имеется класс для работы с DialogFragment

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

DB db;
String name;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    db.open();
    name = getArguments().getString("name");

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);

    final EditText dialogIngredients = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ingredientsEdit);
    final EditText dialogZnachenie= (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_znachenieEdit);
    final Spinner dialogUnits = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_units_spinner);


    return builder
            .setTitle("Диалоговое окно")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.havka)
            .setMessage("Впишите продукт, меру, единицы измерения. " + '\n' +
                    "Например: Курица 500 гр.")
            .setView(dialogView)
            .setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Добавить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {


                    if (dialogIngredients.getText().length() == 0 || dialogZnachenie.getText().length() == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Заполните все поля и список", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        db.addRec(R.drawable.ic_create_black, R.drawable.draw_name_eat, name , dialogIngredients.getText().toString(),
                                dialogZnachenie.getText().toString(),
                                dialogUnits.getSelectedItem().toString(), 0);


                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                dialogIngredients.getText().toString() +
                                        dialogZnachenie.getText().toString() +
                                        dialogUnits.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            })
            .create();
}
```

}

Фрагмент CountingFragment, в котором это диалоговое окно срабатывает по нажатию кнопки

```
public class CountingFragment extends Fragment implements 
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> { 

private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1; 

public static final int COUNT_LOADER = 2; 


ListView lvData;
DB db;
private CursorCountingAdapter scAdapter;
Button addCount;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_counting, container, false);

    lvData = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.lvDataCount);


    db = new DB(getActivity());
    db.open();

    scAdapter = new CursorCountingAdapter(getActivity(), null);

    lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter); 
    registerForContextMenu(lvData);
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(COUNT_LOADER, null, this);
    lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            boolean isCheck = scAdapter.isChecked();

            db.changeChecked(id, isCheck ? 0 : 1);

                  getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(COUNT_LOADER).forceLoad();
        }
    });

//по нажатию кнопки срабатывает диалог

    addCount = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.add_count_but);
    addCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CustomDialogFragment dialog = new CustomDialogFragment();

            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            String name = getArguments().getString("name");

            arguments.putString("name", name);

            dialog.setArguments(arguments);

            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "custom");
        }
    });



    return v;

}

@Override
public void onStart() { 
    super.onStart();
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(COUNT_LOADER, null, this);


public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, CM_DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.delete_record);
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {
        // получаем из пункта контекстного меню данные по пункту списка
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();

        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(COUNT_LOADER).forceLoad();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String name = getArguments().getString("name"); //строка для получения аргументов создается в onCreateLoader
    return new CursorLoaderCount(getActivity(), db, id, name);
}


@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    scAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
    scAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}

static class CursorLoaderCount extends CursorLoader {
    Cursor cursor;
    final int LoaderId;
    DB db;
    String name;

    public CursorLoaderCount(Context context, DB db, int id, String name) {
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
        LoaderId = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {

        switch (LoaderId){

            case COUNT_LOADER:
                cursor = db.getIngrNew(name);
                break;
        }

        return cursor;
    }
}
```

}

Класс для работы с БД. Здесь нужно прописать метод, который будет добавлять данные через ContentValues именно в то блюдо, в которое мы перешли. Не получается додумать метод

```
public class DB {


    private static final String DB_NAME = "mealhbhybl"; 
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1; 
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "myMeals";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_MEAL = "mealing";
    public static final String COLUMN_IMG = "img";
    public static final String COLUMN_INGR = "ingr";
    public static final String COLUMN_VAL = "val";
    public static final String COLUMN_UNI = "uni";
    public static final String COLUMN_IMGV3 = "img3";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHEKBOX = "myCheck";

    private static final String DB_CREATE =
            "create table " + DB_TABLE + "(" +
                    COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                    COLUMN_IMG + " integer, " +
                    COLUMN_MEAL + " text, " +
                    COLUMN_IMGV3 + " integer, " +
                    COLUMN_INGR + " text, " +
                    COLUMN_VAL + " text, " +
                    COLUMN_UNI + " text, " +
                    COLUMN_CHEKBOX + " integer" +
                    ");";

    private final Context mCtx;


    private DBHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DB(Context ctx) {
        mCtx = ctx;
    }



    public void changeChecked (long id, int check){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_CHEKBOX, check);
        mDB.update(DB_TABLE, contentValues, COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);

    }



    public void open() {
        mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    public void close() {
        if (mDBHelper != null) mDBHelper.close();
    }


    public Cursor getAllData() {
        return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, DB.COLUMN_MEAL, DB.COLUMN_IMG, DB.COLUMN_INGR, DB.COLUMN_VAL, DB.COLUMN_UNI}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }


    public Cursor getMeal () {
        return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_MEAL, COLUMN_IMGV3}, null, null, COLUMN_MEAL, null, null);
    }

public Cursor getIngrNew (String name) {
    return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{String.valueOf(COLUMN_CHEKBOX), COLUMN_ID, DB.COLUMN_INGR, DB.COLUMN_VAL, DB.COLUMN_UNI}, DB.COLUMN_MEAL + " = ?", new String[]{name}, null, null, null);
}

public int delMeal (String name) {
    return mDB.delete(DB_TABLE, DB.COLUMN_MEAL + " = ?", new String[]{name});
}

//Предполагаю, что метод должен быть примерно таким
    public void addRec(int img, int img3, String mealing, String ingr, String val, String uni, int checkbox) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_UNI, uni);
        cv.put(COLUMN_VAL, val);
        cv.put(COLUMN_INGR, ingr);
        cv.put(COLUMN_MEAL, mealing);
        cv.put(COLUMN_IMG, img);
        cv.put(COLUMN_IMGV3, img3);
        cv.put(COLUMN_CHEKBOX, checkbox);

        mDB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
    }


    public void delRec(long id) {
        mDB.delete(DB_TABLE, COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }


    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                        int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


        }
    }

}
```

То есть при нажатии setPositiveButton диалога данные должны записаться в SQlite

Класс для работы с блюдами DishFragment

```
public class DishFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1;
ListView lvData;
DB db;
SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
private AdView mAdView;

public static final int DISH_LOADER = 0; 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dish, container, false);
    lvData = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.lvDataDish);

    db = new DB(getActivity());
    db.open();


    // формируем столбцы сопоставления
    String[] from = new String[] {DB.COLUMN_IMGV3, DB.COLUMN_MEAL,}; 
    final int[] to = new int[] {R.id.mealIvImg, R.id.mealTvMeal}; 

    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.item_meal,
            null,
            from,
            to,
            0);



    lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);
    lvData.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    registerForContextMenu(lvData);

    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(DISH_LOADER, null, this);


    return v;
}

@Override
public void onStart() { 
    super.onStart();

    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(DISH_LOADER, null, this);

    Log.w("start", "onStart");

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.w("resume", "onResume");
}



@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.w("stop", "onStop");
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.w("destroy", "onDestroy");

}



public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, CM_DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.delete_meal);
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {
        // получаем из пункта контекстного меню данные по пункту списка
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();

        TextView myTextView = (TextView)acmi.targetView.findViewById(R.id.mealTvMeal);

        String key = myTextView.getText().toString();

        db.delMeal(key);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Удалено блюдо " + key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        // получаем новый курсор с данными
        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(DISH_LOADER).forceLoad();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    return new MyCursorLoader(getActivity(), db, id);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    scAdapter.swapCursor(data);

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    scAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DB.COLUMN_MEAL));


    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    CountingFragment countingFragment = new CountingFragment();
    CustomDialogFragment customDialogFragment = new CustomDialogFragment();

    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();

    arguments.putString("name", name);

    countingFragment.setArguments(arguments);
    customDialogFragment.setArguments(arguments);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId(), countingFragment).addToBackStack(null).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit();

}


static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader{

    Cursor cursor;
    final int LoaderID;
    DB db;

    public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DB db, int id) {
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
        LoaderID = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        switch (LoaderID) {
            case DISH_LOADER:
                cursor = db.getMeal();
                break;
        }

        return cursor;
    }
}
```

}

Класс Meals

```
public class Meals extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks {



private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1; 
public static final int MEALS_LOADER = 1;
private ListView lvData;
private DB db;
private SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
private EditText nameProductEdit;
private EditText ingredientsEdit;
private TextView dannie_meal;
private TextView dannie_name_meal;
private EditText znachenieEdit;
private Spinner unitsSpinner;
private Button buttonNextNazvanie;
private Button button_dobavit;
private Button button_sohr;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.meals);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    nameProductEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_product);

    ingredientsEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ingredientsEdit);
    dannie_meal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    dannie_name_meal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    znachenieEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.znachenieEdit);
    unitsSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.units_spinner);
    button_dobavit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_dobavit);


    button_sohr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sohr);
    button_sohr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    buttonNextNazvanie = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_next_nazvanie);
    buttonNextNazvanie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (view.getId() == R.id.button_next_nazvanie){

                if (nameProductEdit.getText().length() == 0){

                    nameProductEdit.setText("");
                    nameProductEdit.requestFocus();
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Meals.this, "Введите название блюда", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }

                else {

                    buttonNextNazvanie.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    dannie_name_meal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    button_dobavit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    button_sohr.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    znachenieEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    unitsSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    dannie_meal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    ingredientsEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ingredientsEdit.requestFocus();

                    nameProductEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

        }

    });



    // открываем подключение к БД
    db = new DB(this);
    db.open();

    String[] from = new String[] {DB.COLUMN_IMG, DB.COLUMN_MEAL, DB.COLUMN_INGR, DB.COLUMN_VAL, DB.COLUMN_UNI};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.ivImg, R.id.textViewMeal, R.id.tvIngr, R.id.tvVal, R.id.tvUni};


    // создаем адаптер и настраиваем список
    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
    lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);
    lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);

    // добавляем контекстное меню к списку
    registerForContextMenu(lvData);

    // создаем лоадер для чтения данных
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(MEALS_LOADER, null, this);
}

// обработка нажатия кнопки
public void onButtonClick(View view) {

    if (ingredientsEdit.getText().length() == 0
            || znachenieEdit.getText().length() == 0) {
        ingredientsEdit.setText("");
        znachenieEdit.setText("");
        ingredientsEdit.requestFocus();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Заполните все поля и список", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

    }
    else {
        // добавляем запись
        db.addRec(R.drawable.ic_create_black, R.drawable.draw_name_eat, nameProductEdit.getText().toString(), ingredientsEdit.getText().toString(),
                znachenieEdit.getText().toString(),
                unitsSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), 0);

        ingredientsEdit.setText("");
        znachenieEdit.setText("");
        unitsSpinner.setSelection(0);

        ingredientsEdit.requestFocus();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Добавлено в блюдо " + nameProductEdit.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        // получаем новый курсор с данными
        getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(MEALS_LOADER).forceLoad();
    }
}


public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, CM_DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.delete_record);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() { //правильно обновляются старые данные при переключении между фрагментами
    super.onStart();
    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(MEALS_LOADER, null, this);
    Appodeal.onResume(this, Appodeal.BANNER);
    Log.w("start", "onStart!!");

}


public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {
        // получаем из пункта контекстного меню данные по пункту списка
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        // извлекаем id записи и удаляем соответствующую запись в БД
        db.delRec(acmi.id);
        // получаем новый курсор с данными
        getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(MEALS_LOADER).forceLoad();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bndl) {
    return new MyCursorLoader(this, db);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Object data) {
    scAdapter.swapCursor((Cursor) data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {

}

private static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

    DB db;

    private MyCursorLoader(Context context, DB db) {
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        Cursor cursor = db.getAllData();
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long) 0.8f);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cursor;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для записи данных в определенный раздел (блюдо в вашем случае) необходимо в диалог передавать ключ, который будет связывать эти записи с нужным разделом (поле *name* в вашем случае):

В вызывающем фрагменте при открытии диалога передаем ключ.

CountingFragment (только относящийся к проблеме код):

```
public class CountingFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> { 

int UPDATE_LIST = 1;

 ...
    addCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CustomDialogFragment dialog = new CustomDialogFragment();
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            String name = getArguments().getString("name");
            arguments.putString("name", name);
            dialog.setArguments(arguments);
            dialog.setTargetFragment(CountingFragment.this, UPDATE_LIST);
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "custom");
        }
    });

...

// обновление списка при добавлении записи:

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case UPDATE_LIST: getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(COUNT_LOADER, null, this);
        return;
        }
    }
}
```

В диалоге получаем ключ, и делаем запись в БД (только относящийся к проблеме код):

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    String name;
    int UPDATE_LIST = 1;;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        name = getArguments().getString("name");
        ...

        return builder
            .setPositiveButton("Добавить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {

                        if (dialogIngredients.getText().length() == 0 || dialogZnachenie.getText().length() == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Заполните все поля и список", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        DB db = new DB(getContext());
                        db.open();
                        db.addRec(R.drawable.ic_create_black, R.drawable.draw_name_eat, name , dialogIngredients.getText().toString(),
                                dialogZnachenie.getText().toString(),
                                dialogUnits.getSelectedItem().toString(), 0);
                        // отправляем признак, что требуется обновить список
                        update();

                        }
                }
            })
            .create();
    }

    void update(){
        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK , new Intent());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам класс с `DialogFragment` ?
Создайте такой класс:

```
public class extra {
    public void add(Context ctx, final DB db){
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);

        final EditText dialogIngredients = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ingredientsEdit);
        final EditText dialogZnachenie= (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_znachenieEdit);
        final Spinner dialogUnits = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_units_spinner);

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Диалоговое окно");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Впишите продукт, меру, единицы измерения. " + '\n' + "Например: Курица 500 гр.");
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Добавить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        if (dialogIngredients.getText() != null && dialogZnachenie.getText() != null){
                            db.addRec(
                                IMG, 
                                IMG_V3, 
                                MEALING, 
                                dialogIngredients.getText().toString(), 
                                dialogZnachenie.getText().toString(), 
                                dialogUnits.getSelectedItem().toString(), 
                                CHECKBOX
                            );
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

А вызывайте из Fragmenta так:

```
new extra().add(getActivity(), db);
```

Кстати у вас в Dialogе нет других форм и т.д, вместо IMG, IMG_V3, MEALING и CheckBox поставьте свои значения.

Comment: DialogFragment позволяет "безболезненно" переносить повороты устройства, без потери текущего состояния. Ваш код никак не решает проблему в вопросе (привязка данных из диалога  к определенному блюду), а просто добавляет новую запись.